# Icosahedral form of $\mathrm{SO}_3(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-groups, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Does there exist a linear algebraic group whose real points are $ \mathrm{SO}_3(\mathbb{R}) $ and whose integer points are the icosahedral group?

Let $ \phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} $ be the golden ratio. $ \mathbb{Z}[\phi] $ is a ring of algebraic integers so I am also fine with a linear algebraic group whose real points are $ \mathrm{SO}_3(\mathbb{R}) $ and whose $ \mathbb{Z}[\phi] $ points are the icosahedral group.

Generating matrices for the standard icosahedral group are given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedral_symmetry in the section on coxeter group generators. Mostly the generators look like $ \mathbb{Z}[\phi] $ points of some integral form of $ \mathrm{SO}_3(\mathbb{R}) $. However there are factors of $ \frac{1}{2} $ everywhere that I don't know how to deal with.

Comment: [The ring of icosians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosian) is a maximal order in the division algebra gotten by restricting the coefficients of (Hamiltonian) quaternions from the reals to the subfield $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$. This means that all the icosians can be represented by $8\times8$ integer matrices. I don't know if this really helps answering your question though? You need to match those with an 8-dimensional real representation of $SO_3$ and then hope for the best. Sorry that I am not of much help :-(

Comment: @jyrki might those eight dimensions have something to do with the primitive roots $\bmod 15$? I am getting that symmetry from the matrix eigenvalues.

Comment: Possibly @Oscar. But I think we cannot ignore the difference between having all the eigenvalues and having a ring homomorphism $\Bbb{I}\to M_{8\times 8}(\Bbb{Z}$. Here $\Bbb{I}$ stands for the ring of icosians. By restriction this gives us a homomorphism from the icosahedral group to $GL_8(\Bbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}$Over $\ZZ$, the answer is no. As Venkataramana showed in [an answer to your recent MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/417672/297), if $\Gamma$ is the integer points of an integral form of $SO(3)$, then $|\Gamma|$ divides $24$, and can't be $60$.

Over $\ZZ[\phi]$, the answer is yes. For convenience, abbreviate $R=\ZZ[\phi]$. Let $\Lambda = \{ (x_1,x_2,x_3) \in R^3 : x_1+\phi x_2 + \phi^2 x_3 \in 2 R \}$. I will show that

1. The group of symmetries in $O(3)$ which preserve the $R$-module $\Lambda$ is the group of symmetries of the icosahedron with vertices $(\pm \phi, \pm 1,  0)$, $(0,\pm \phi,  \pm 1 )$, $(\pm 1, 0, \pm \phi)$. If you want just the rotational symmetries of the icosahedron, you can limit yourself to $SO(3)$ rather than $O(3)$.
2. There is an algebraic group defined over $R$ such that, for every $R$-algebra $S$, the $S$-points are the symmetries of $\Lambda \otimes_R S$ which preserve the quadratic form $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2$.
   In particular, the $R$ points are the symmetries of the icosahedron and the $\mathbb{R}$ points are $O(3)$. Again, it would be easy to limit yourself to $SO(3)$ by asking for symmetries with determinant $1$.

---

Verification of $(1)$: Set $I = \{ (\pm \phi, \pm 1,  0), (0,\pm \phi,  \pm 1 ), (\pm 1, 0, \pm \phi)\}$. We first notice that $I$ is in $\Lambda$ and that $I$ generates $\Lambda$ as an $R$-module. Therefore, any linear transformation preserving $I$ must take $\Lambda$ to itself. This shows that the group of rotational symmetries of $I$ is contained in the group symmetries in $SO(3)$ which preserve $\Lambda$.

Conversely, we will show that $I$ is precisely the set of vectors in $\Lambda$ with $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 = 1+\phi^2 = \tfrac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. This will then imply that any orthogonal symmetry preserving $\Lambda$ must preserve $I$.

Indeed, suppose that $(x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \Lambda$ with $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=\tfrac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Put $x_i = \tfrac{a_i+b_i \sqrt{5}}{2}$ with $a_i \equiv b_i \bmod 2$. Then, looking at the rational parts of both sides, we have $\tfrac{1}{4} \left( a_1^2 + 5 b_1^2 +a_2^2 + 5 b_2^2+a_3^2 + 5 b_3^2 \right) = \tfrac{5}{2}$ or $a_1^2 + 5 b_1^2 +a_2^2 + 5 b_2^2+a_3^2 + 5 b_3^2 = 10$. The only numbers of the form $a^2+5b^2$ with $a \equiv b \bmod 2$ that are less than $10$ are $0$, $4$ and $6$, so the only way to write $10$ as a sum of three of these is some permutation of $0+4+6$. That means that $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ must be some permutation of $(0, \pm 1, \pm \phi^{\pm 1})$. The condition that $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=\tfrac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ forces the exponent of $\phi$ to be $+1$ (otherwise, we have $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1+\phi^{-2} = \tfrac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2}$), and the condition that $x_1 + \phi x_2 + \phi^2 x_3$ be in $2R$ forces $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ to be a cyclic permutation of $(\pm \phi, \pm 1, 0)$.

It is fun to look at solutions to $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 = r$ in $\Lambda$ for other values of $r$. Taking $r=3$, we get the $8$ points $(\pm 1, \pm 1, \pm 1)$ and the $12$ cyclic permutations of $(\pm \phi, 0, \pm \phi^{-1})$, which form a dodecahedron. Taking $r=4$, we get the $6$ points $(\pm 2, 0,0)$ and the $24$ cyclic permutations of $(\pm \phi^{-1}, \pm 1, \pm \phi)$, which form an [icosidodecahron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosidodecahedron). It might be fun to plot these points for some large $r$ and get some shape with many vertices and icosahedral symmetry.

---

Verfication of $(2)$: $\Lambda$ is a free $R$-module; one choice of basis is $v_1:=(\phi, 1,0)$, $v_2:=(1,0,\phi)$, $v_3:=(0,\phi,1)$. Write linear transformations of $\Lambda$ in this basis. The condition that a matrix takes $\Lambda$ to $\Lambda$ then just says that the matrix has entries in $R$, and more generally the condition that a matrix takes $\Lambda \otimes_R S$ to itself says that it is a $3 \times 3$ matrix with entries in $S$. So our linear algebraic group will be the subgroup of $GL_3$ preserving the quadratic form given by writing the standard Euclidean norm in the $v_i$ basis. (And, if you want to limit yourself to $SO_3$ rather than $O_3$, add the condition that the determinant is $1$.)

Explicitly, that quadratic form is
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
1+\phi^2 & \phi & \phi \\ 
 \phi & 1+\phi^2 & \phi \\ 
\phi & \phi & 1+\phi^2 \\ 
\end{bmatrix} = 
\phi \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{5} & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & \sqrt{5} & 1 \\ 1&1&\sqrt{5} \end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Keep calm and work out eigenvalues of those matrices. (Don't worry about the equations being cubic, they are reducible.) You find that they are algebraic integers in $\mathbb Z[\xi,\omega]$ where

- $\xi$ is a primitive fifth root of unity.
- $\omega$ has its common meaning as a primitive cube root of unity.

For example, among the generators whose eigenvalues contain fifth roots of unity is what WP lists as $M_{32}$, with eigenvalues $1$ and what would be $\xi,\xi^4$ if we take $\xi$ as $\cos(72°)+i\sin(72°)=(\phi-1)/2+i\sqrt{1-1/(4\phi^2)}$.

The real algebraic integers in $\mathbb Z[\xi,\omega]$ are a superset of $\mathbb Z[\phi]$. We may describe them succinctly as $\mathbb Z[2\cos(24°)]$.

Comment: I see. Could you comment on how we can turn this in to an explicit integral form for $ SO_3 $ (whose integral points will indeed be the icosahedral group)?